# como deixar uma pasta definida para quando for salvar? e uma pasta definida para abrir arquivos?

Tags: delphi-10

Gostaria de travar as pastas, para que não pudesse ir buscar arquivos ou salvar arquivos em outras pastas, apenas nas definidas, EX de Pastas: `c:\banco_de_dados` e uma outra chamada `c:\FTP_Servidor`

No caso seria para deixar o caminho setado para enviar o banco de dados para o servidor de forma automática.

parte do fonte:

```
begin

if OpenDialog1.Execute then
if SaveDialog1.Execute then

idftp1.Put(OpenDialog1.FileName, '/projeto_ftp/banco/' + ExtractFileName(SaveDialog1.FileName));

  // ShowMessage('Transferido');

idftp1.Get(SaveDialog1.FileName, '/projeto_ftp/' );
```

Comment: Você poderia setar o caminho fixo no no seu fonte... Mas sem ver seu fonte fica difícil ajudar, se puder altere sua pergunta e coloque um trecho do seu fonte de onde quer fazer esse "travamento".

Comment: @Matheus Ribeiro coloquei o trecho que estou usando para essa parte, valeu por notar, eu realmente esqueci de por o fonte ali. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode validar o caminho após a pessoa selecionar o arquivo, desta forma

```
OpenDialog1.initialDir := 'C:\Seu\caminho\busca\';
SaveDialog1.initialDir := 'C:\Seu\caminho\salvar\';

if(OpenDialog1.Execute)then
begin
  if(ExtractFilePath(OpenDialog1.FileName) = 'C:\Seu\caminho\busca\')then
  begin
    if(SaveDialog1.Execute)then
    begin
      if(ExtractFilePath(SaveDialog1.FileName) <> 'C:\Seu\caminho\salvar\')then
      begin
        idftp1.Put(OpenDialog1.FileName, '/projeto_ftp/banco/' + ExtractFileName(SaveDialog1.FileName));
        // ShowMessage('Transferido');
        idftp1.Get(SaveDialog1.FileName, '/projeto_ftp/' );
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Para que seja invisível para o cliente, você teria que setar os caminhos no fonte manualmente sem a opção dele poder selecionar...

Um exemplo seria assim:

```
procedure SeuMetodo();
var
  cCaminhoSalvar: String;
  cCaminhoServidor: String;
  cCaminhoArquivo: String;
begin
  cCaminhoSalvar   := 'C:\Seu\caminho\salvar\';
  cCaminhoServidor := 'servidor\arquivos';
  cCaminhoArquivo  := 'C:\Seu\caminho\busca\arquivoTal.bd'; {Aqui teria que tratar o nome do arquivo, caso exista mais de um na pasta}

  idftp1.Put(cCaminhoArquivo, cCaminhoServidor + ExtractFileName(cCaminhoArquivo));
  // ShowMessage('Transferido');
  idftp1.Get(cCaminhoSalvar, cCaminhoServidor);
end; 

(*Não lembro a ordem correta dos parâmetros do PUT e GET*)
```

*Obs.: Para automatizar sua aplicação, você poderia criar um serviço para a mesma e dentro do serviço utilizar uma thread com um contador dentro dela e então, por exemplo, a cada 1hr ela faz as validações necessárias e envia seus dados.*

Comment: O problema é que preciso que o cliente nem saiba o que está acontecendo, de preferência rodando a aplicação em modo oculto no Windows, e com upload automático, vc acha que isso é possível?

Comment: demorei pra voltar, por motivos de força maior..... bem no Agendador de tarefas do Windows consigo rodar a aplicação de forma programada, mas tem alguma outra forma pra automatizar a tarefa???

Comment: Para o que seja invisível para o cliente, você teria que setar os caminhos no fonte manualmente sem a opção dele poder selecionar... Para automatizar sua aplicação, você poderia criar um serviço para a mesma e dentro do serviço utilizar uma thread com um contador dentro dela e então, por exemplo, a cada 1hr ela faz as validações necessárias e envia seus dados.

Comment: Quando conseguir tempo vou pesquisar sobre essa Thread pois desconheço essa parte.

Comment: Pesquise bem e entenda como a mesma funciona pois é meio complicado trabalhar com Threads, como no seu caso, por você não conhecer muito.

Comment: Sim, Obrigado por tentar me ajudar, você me deu umas dicas importantes!

Comment: Se o caminho é fixo não precisa do open/savedialog. é só fazer o get/put no ftp.

Comment: @RicardoAlvesCarvalho Foi o que eu citei em meu comentário, irei modificar minha resposta para que fique destacado!